# Unable to validate a form using Javascript; PHP redirect issues?

Tags: php, javascript, html, wamp

I've coded a simple form for a friend's hobby; basically, we are trying to guess the starting lineup for a couple of teams in the 2010 FIFAWorld Cup (just for the kicks).

Anyway, I need to validate the following form. All the Javascript functions appear to function well because if i just call them **outside** of the  tag, everything works fine. Now, i want to perform some basic client-side validation (i know, it isn't safe blabla but it's a hobby, so it isn't relevant) and then pass the form to another page where a PHP (currently using WAMP Server 2.0) script will collect the data and store it in the database.

Here's the form:

```
<form name ="formPT" id="formPT" action="" onsubmit="return ValidaTudo();" method="post">
<a><img src="icons/paises/portugal-flag-icon.png" alt="portugal" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle"> Portugal</a>
<table id="tabela_PT" cellspacing="0" summary="Equipa">
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col" abbr="Nome" class="nobg">Nome</th>
<th scope="col" abbr="Posicao">Posição</th>
<th scope="col" abbr="Escolha">Escolha</th>
<th scope="col" abbr="Anterior">Escolha Anterior</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td scope="row" abbr="Jogador" class="spec">Eduardo</td><td>Guarda-redes</td><td><select  name="escolhaPT"><option value="EF">EF</option><option value="SP">SP</option><option value="NU" selected="selected">NU</option></select> </td><td>NU</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" abbr="Jogador" class="spec">Beto</td><td>Guarda-redes</td><td><select  name="escolhaPT"><option value="EF">EF</option><option value="SP">SP</option><option value="NU" selected="selected">NU</option></select> </td><td>NU</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" abbr="Jogador" class="spec">Daniel Fernandes</td><td>Guarda-redes</td><td><select  name="escolhaPT"><option value="EF">EF</option><option value="SP">SP</option><option value="NU" selected="selected">NU</option></select> </td><td>NU</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" abbr="Jogador" class="spec">Paulo Ferreira</td><td>Defesa</td><td><select  name="escolhaPT"><option value="EF">EF</option><option value="SP">SP</option><option value="NU" selected="selected">NU</option></select> </td><td>NU</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" abbr="Jogador" class="spec">Miguel</td><td>Defesa</td><td><select  name="escolhaPT"><option value="EF">EF</option><option value="SP">SP</option><option value="NU" selected="selected">NU</option></select> </td><td>NU</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" abbr="Jogador" class="spec">Ricardo Carvalho</td><td>Defesa</td><td><select  name="escolhaPT"><option value="EF">EF</option><option value="SP">SP</option><option value="NU" selected="selected">NU</option></select> </td><td>NU</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" abbr="Jogador" class="spec">Bruno Alves</td><td>Defesa</td><td><select  name="escolhaPT"><option value="EF">EF</option><option value="SP">SP</option><option value="NU" selected="selected">NU</option></select> </td><td>NU</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" abbr="Jogador" class="spec">Ricardo Costa</td><td>Defesa</td><td><select  name="escolhaPT"><option value="EF">EF</option><option value="SP">SP</option><option value="NU" selected="selected">NU</option></select> </td><td>NU</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" abbr="Jogador" class="spec">Fabio Coentrao</td><td>Defesa</td><td><select  name="escolhaPT"><option value="EF">EF</option><option value="SP">SP</option><option value="NU" selected="selected">NU</option></select> </td><td>NU</td></tr>
<tr><td scope="row" abbr="Jogador" class="spec">Pepe</td><td>Médio</td><td><select  name="escolhaPT"><option value="EF">EF</option><option value="SP">SP</option><option value="NU" selected="selected">NU</option></select> </td><td>NU</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>        
<input type='submit' value='Check Field' />
</form>
```

Now for a bit of Javascript:

```
 function ValidaTudo()
{
    alert('debug: validating...')
    if(Valida('PT'))
    {
        alert('fine!');
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('useless validation message but wth');
        return false;
    }
}
```

There's more javascript functions, obviously, but:

- I'm not getting *any* alert popup from that javascript function!
- The page is, quite simply, redirected to index.php so i'm assuming it's a PHP/WAMP issue... i rebooted WAMP quite a couple of times, but no luck so far. I haven't reboot my PC although I think I should.

What am i missing? Thanks in advance guys!

PS: Yes, the form isn't sending the data to any page at all; i know that; it does not have any effect on the weird behavior, i've tried it.

Edit: Here's the rest of the validating functions. They are used to check if the user followed certains rules (e.g.: selecting exactly 11 players; 1 goal-keeper; at least 3 defenders, etc...). I'm passing a couple of parameters because in the full form we're trying to guess the players of 4 teams (Portugal, Spain, Brazil and Argentina) - hence 4 forms, each with a different ID (based on the nation's identifier -> {PT, BR, AR, ES}
Here's the rest of the functions **(keep in mind that they work outside of the form)**:

```
function Valida (textstring) 
{
    var error_msg = null; 

    if(!valida_11(textstring.toUpperCase()))
    {
        error_msg = 'Erro para a equipa ' + textstring.toUpperCase() + ': deve selecionar apenas 11 jogadores efectivos';
        alert(error_msg);
    }

    if (!valida_gk(textstring.toUpperCase()))
    {
        error_msg = 'Erro para a equipa ' + textstring.toUpperCase() + ': deve selecionar um e um só 1 guarda-redes efectivo';
        alert(error_msg);
    }

    if (!valida_def(textstring.toUpperCase()))
    {
        error_msg = 'Erro para a equipa ' + textstring.toUpperCase() + ': deve selecionar um mínino de 3 defesas efectivo';
        alert(error_msg);
    }

    if(error_msg == null)
        return true;
    else return false;
}

function valida_11(tbl)
{
    var ef = 0;
    var input_list = document.getElementsByName('escolha' + tbl);

    for(var i = 0; i < input_list.length; i++) 
    {
        var a = input_list[i].value;
        if(a == "EF")
            ef++;
    }

    if (ef == 11)
        return true;
    else return false;
}

function valida_gk(tbl)
{   
    var ef = 0;
    var gks = conta_gks(tbl);
    var input_list = document.getElementsByName('escolha' + tbl);

    for(var i = 0; i < gks; i++) 
    {
        var a = input_list[i].value;
        if(a == "EF")
            ef++;
    }

    if (ef == 1)
        return true;
    else return false;
}

function valida_def(tbl)
{
    var defs = conta_defs(tbl);
    var gks = conta_gks(tbl);

    var ef = 0;
    var input_list = document.getElementsByName('escolha' + tbl);

    for(var i = gks-1; i < gks + defs; i++) 
    {
        var a = input_list[i].value;
        if(a == "EF")
            ef++;
    }

    if (ef >= 3)
        return true;
    else return false;
}

function conta_defs(tbl)
{
    var defs = 0;
    var tabela = document.getElementById('tabela_' + tbl);

    for(var i = 1; i < tabela.getElementsByTagName("tr").length; i++)
    {
        var linha = tabela.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
        var celula = linha.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

        if(celula.innerHTML == "Defesa")
            defs++;
    }

    return defs;
}


function conta_gks(tbl)
{
    var gk = 0;
    var tabela = document.getElementById('tabela_' + tbl);

    for(var i = 1; i < tabela.getElementsByTagName("tr").length; i++)
    {
        var linha = tabela.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
        var celula = linha.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

        if(celula.innerHTML == "Guarda-redes")
            gk++;
    }

    return gk;
}
```

Edit 2: The same happens in other browsers, like IE 7.
Edit 3: Rebooted the PC but the issue remains... :/

Okay, i managed to put the page online @: http://testing.freeoda.com/teste.html
Give it a spin. Over here, i'm getting a 404 error; no JS function is called....

Comment: Further down the page; i didn't paste it because i'm not even getting the alerts from the ValidaTudo function. Plus, the entire set of Javascript functions work fine when outside of the form tag.

I can paste it though, it's no problem.

Comment: `if(Valida('PT'))` where's the function definition?

Comment: Does the `<form>` with the `onsubmit` attribute appear correctly in e.g. Firebug or another DOM inspector? Do you have an example page?

Comment: Yes, Firebug shows absolutely nothing. I've used it intensely during the development of the rest of site and of this very form as well when I tested the rest of the functions.

Comment: You mean ‘it doesn't show an error’ or ‘the form/attribute is not shown’?

Comment: I mean I load the page, fire up Firebug, I fill in the form and press Submit. Then, the page goes straight to "index.php" without showing anything at all, no alert boxes, no errors on Firebug / Firefox's console, nothing...

Comment: Have you try with just a 

function ValidaTudo()
{
   return true;
}

Comment: Hmm, its working fine for me (FireFox 3.6.3 Mac) can you put a link to the full file that is not working?

Comment: @matkh i have, but the problem's still there.
@Scott, hmmm yeah gimme a sec.

Comment: Frak, I can't seem to enter my FTP account from here (i'm not at home...). Still, if you guys aren't having any issues with the form then that's good news i guess. WTF is happening in here, i've just rebooted the PC and it's still the same

Comment: Working here, too (Firefox 3.5.9 and Chrome 5.0.375.70 beta Ubuntu)

Comment: This has got to be some kind of weird Wamp error...

Comment: Hmmmm nop, it doesn't seem to work in that crappy web host either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing...
My bad. I messed up because I'm using a crappy menu bar made by another programmer who forgot to close the  tag; everything was working as it was supposed to, because the actual form we're seeing was actually inside another one. /face-palm

**My apologies to you all, thank you for your time and patience.**

Comment: I hate it when you spend time working through PHP, JavaScript, CSS, etc. and it turns out the problem is malformed HTML!

Comment: Indeed. I lost 6 hours to this crap today.

Answer (score 0):

Bacause form is refreshing page even if there is no action="".
Try to write instead `onsubmit="return ValidaTudo();"` this: `action="javascript:ValidaTudo();"`
)))

Comment: and where is ";" after `alert('debug: validating...')` you missed it?

Comment: Nice call; yes, it was missing from the test page. Strangely enough, no error is being outputted!

Still, it's not working :(

Comment: you can use opera error console and opera dragnfly to locate js bugs.

Comment: Or i can open Firefox's console and use Firebug to locate bugs... which i did. And *still* it doesn't work.

Comment: if `<form name ="formPT" id="formPT" action="javascript:ValidaTudo();" method="post">` returns false;)))

Comment: By the way, I placed a copy of the test file online (check the question). Does it work over there?

Comment: My fault, i made a silly mistake by trusting a 3rd party code.... sorry dude, thanks for your help.